# SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement (в print)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
>>> a = 2
    b = 1
>>> while a < 32:
         print("N"b"-"a " ")
         b=b+1
         a=a*2
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка? Он выдаёт ошибку которая в заголовке. Код нумерует степени двойки до 32ух.
Хочу что бы программа в итоге написала 
1-2 2-4 3-8 4-16

Comment: Чего вы ожидаете от конструкции `print("N"b=a)`?

Comment: Интересно а что вы хотели сделать с переменной b?Одну переменную присвоить другой?Так нельзя, переменным можно присваивать только значения, например числовые или текстовые, но никак не другие переменные. print("N" b=a)

Comment: @Den555, что-то ерунда какая-то...

Comment: @Den555, таки можно переменным присваивать значения из других переменных. `a = 5; b=a; print(b)` напечатает `5`.

Comment: Вот теперь исправил, но почему то не работает программа всёравно.

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Что вы ожидаете от ``print("N"b"="a)``?

Comment: Что бы на выходе программа дала:                                                                                                                    1=2 2=4 3=8 4=16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Непонятно, чего вы ожидаете от вызова `print("N"b=a)`, запись вида `var=val` при вызове функций в питоне означает явную передачу аргумента по имени, а это явно не то, чего вы хотели. Да и запятую вы явно пропустили: `"N"` и `b=a` - две разных инструкции, что и смутило интерпретатор в строке `print("N"b=a)` и вызвало ошибку "multiple statements", коих у вас 2. Чтобы исправить ошибку, либо передавайте 1 аргумент в `print()`, либо передавайте аргументы через запятую: `print("N", b=a)`, но тогда получите другую ошибку, т.к. аргумента `b` у функции `print()` нет.

***update:***
Автор уточнил, что ожидает на выходе получить подобный вывод

```
1=2
2=4
3=8
...
```

Самый простой способ получить данное поведение - передать несколько аргументов в функцию `print()`: `print(b, "=", a)`. Данная функция будет разделять все передаваемые в нее аргументы пробелом. Если вам важно, чтобы между знаком равно и числами не было пробелов - передавайте пустую строку именованным аргументом `sep=`:
`print(b, "=", a, sep="")`.

Но даже после всех этих исправлений ваша программа будет работать неправильно из-за ключевой ошибки в условии цикла while: вы используете переменную `a` в качестве двойки в степени n, а переменную `b` в качестве этой самой степени, вы хотите вывести первые 32 степени двойки, но при этом условие цикла проверяет переменную, отвечающую за число, а не за степень. Чтобы это исправить, нужно менять переменную в условии цикла на b.
После всех правок получаем работающий код, выводящий все степени двойки с 1 по 31-ю:

```
a = 2
b = 1
while b < 32:
    print(b, "=", a, sep="")
    b=b+1
    a=a*2
```

Comment: Человек самые азы питона изучает и наверняка не поймёт, что такое «явная передача аргумента по имени».